# Imprimir un archivo guardado en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, print

Estoy tratando de imprimir desde windform, resulta que cuando imprimo el documento, me sale la hoja en blanco. 
Este es el codigo con el que trato de imprimir:

```
    private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
    private string stringToPrint;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LeerArchivo();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }

    private void LeerArchivo()
    {
        string docName = "1.pdf";
        string docPath = @"C:\Firmador\";
        printDocument1.DocumentName = docName;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(docPath + docName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            stringToPrint = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int charactersOnPage = 0;
        int linesPerPage = 0;


        e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, this.Font,
            e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
            out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);


        e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, this.Font, Brushes.Black,
            e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);


        stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

        e.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);
    }

    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LeerArchivo();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
```

Esto es lo que contiene stringToPrint:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Me gustaría saber si existe como poder corregirlo o alguna otra forma de imprimir el archivo?Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios puntos donde podría estar el error, vamos a ver si lo podemos aclarar:

### Punto de entrada

Cúal es el punto de entrada? `button1_Click` o `printButton_Click`? Veo que los dos tienen el mismo código en su interior, lo cual es un poco extraño. Lo habitual para ejecutar el mismo código desde dos event handlers (manejadores de eventos) es extraer dicho código a un método privado que es llamado desde ambos event handlers. En cualquier caso, has puesto un punto de interrupción en el punto de entrada y has comprobado si efectivamente pasas por ahí?

### Lectura fichero

Has puesto un punto de entrada y comprobado que tras la asignación `stringToPrint = reader.ReadToEnd();` la variable `stringToPrint` contiene el texto del fichero que quieres imprimir?

### Impresión

Has puesto un punto de interrupción en el método `printDocument1_PrintPage` para comprobar si efectivamente pasas dentro de ese método? Si es así, contiene en ese momento la variable `stringToPrint` el texto que esperas imprimir? El resto del código de ese método me parece correcto, aunque no conozco bien la API de impresión de .NET

Solución alternativa: <sub>Extraida de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6106155/2651069)</sub>

---

Puedes abrir el fichero que quieres imprimir con el programa que esté configurado por defecto en el ordenador para imprimir PDF's, mandar el PDF a la cola de la impresora y cerrar el programa:

```
private void SendToPrinter()
{
   ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
   info.Verb = "print";                          // Seleccionar el programa para imprimir PDF por defecto
   info.FileName = @"C:\Firmador\1.pdf";         // Ruta hacia el fichero que quieres imprimir
   info.CreateNoWindow = true;                   // Hacerlo sin mostrar ventana
   info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; // Y de forma oculta

   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = info;
   p.Start();  // Lanza el proceso

   p.WaitForInputIdle();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);          // Espera 3 segundos
   if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
      p.Kill();                                  // Y cierra el programa de imprimir PDF's
}
```

Comment: gracias @Gua-naiko-che por responder, edite la pregunta mostrando una foto de lo que contiene el archivo.Respondo a tus preguntas:
el punto de entrada es button1_Click que pasa a la función leerArchivo y de ahí va a printDocument1_PrintPage (Comprobando con el punto de interrupción). La solución alternativa que me enviaste funciona quitando el siguiente codigo: if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
      p.Kill();

Comment: Me alegro de que haya funcionado :) En tal caso, te invito a que marques la respuesta como útil y/o aceptada.

Answer (score -1):

corregir sólo esa linea

```
if(stringToPrint.Length > 0)
  { e.HasMorePages = tue; }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).